# How can I place a background image next to a container div a specified distance using CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to position an image to both the left and right of a large container div in the center of the page as shown in the attached image. I am new to CSS and overall front end technologies so this is a challenging task for me.

Below is an image of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: ForStyling]

The HTML looks like the following from the chrome developer tools (Different order content to provided image, but same layout):

```
<div class="page-header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <img src="/Content/clients/Test/logo.png" alt="Test" title="Test">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="sidebars">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="page-header">
      <img src="/Content/clients/Test/logo.png" alt="Test" title="Test">
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group nobottom">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Connote:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-7">
                <p class="form-control-static"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <label for="connote" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Status:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <span>Hooray, your order has been delivered.</span>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">History</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="list-group nobottom">
          <div class="list-group-item ">
            <div style="width: 26px; display: inline-block;">
              <span class=" icon-default"></span>
              <span class="label label-default">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up">&nbsp;</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 80%; display: inline-block;">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Hooray, your order has been delivered.</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">06-May-2016 11:58 AM</p>
              <p class="list-group-item-text" style="white-space: pre-line">CLAYTON SOUTH PDC</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group-item ">
            <div style="width: 26px; display: inline-block;">
              <span class=" icon-default"></span>
              <span class="label label-default">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up">&nbsp;</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 80%; display: inline-block;">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">The driver has your order, they are on the way</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">06-May-2016 05:42 AM</p>
              <p class="list-group-item-text" style="white-space: pre-line">CLAYTON SOUTH PDC</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group-item ">
            <div style="width: 26px; display: inline-block;">
              <span class=" icon-default"></span>
              <span class="label label-default">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up">&nbsp;</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 80%; display: inline-block;">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Get excited your order is not too far away</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">05-May-2016 09:52 PM</p>
              <p class="list-group-item-text" style="white-space: pre-line">MELBOURNE PARCEL FACILITY</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group-item ">
            <div style="width: 26px; display: inline-block;">
              <span class=" icon-default"></span>
              <span class="label label-default">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up">&nbsp;</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 80%; display: inline-block;">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">The couriers have your order, they'll get it to you shortly</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">05-May-2016 10:25 AM</p>
              <p class="list-group-item-text" style="white-space: pre-line">MELBOURNE PARCEL FACILITY DWS</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group-item ">
            <div style="width: 26px; display: inline-block;">
              <span class=" icon-default"></span>
              <span class="label label-default">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up">&nbsp;</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 80%; display: inline-block;">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Hooray, Your order is on its way</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">04-May-2016 12:00 AM</p>
              <p class="list-group-item-text" style="white-space: pre-line"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form action="/" method="get">
          <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group nobottom">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="connote" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Connote:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input id="connote" name="connote" class="col-sm-4 form-control" value="" type="text">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="connote" class="col-sm-4 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Search</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

```
<script src = "/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>    
<script src = "/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>    
<script src = "/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

How can I make those images at the top next to the container appear that distance away on either side and in the same position using css or other formatting techniques?

Help with this would be greatly appreciated

Thank you in advance,

Mark

Comment: where is the css file?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this :

```
<div width="100%">

<div id="image-left">
set a background 
</div>

<div id="main-center"> </div>

<div id="image-right">
set a background 
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to do that. One I made is by using CSS property `float:left` to your images, after you place them inside your container.

I did an example for you. Run the snippet below.

```css
.container{
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
  margin:auto;
  border:1px solid red;
  
}

.image{
  
  float:left;
  margin-left:-60%;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  
}
img{
  width:80px;
  height:auto;
  
}
.image2{
  
 float:left;
 margin-left:120%;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Adidas_Logo.svg/2000px-Adidas_Logo.svg.png"></div>
<div class="image2"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Adidas_Logo.svg/2000px-Adidas_Logo.svg.png"></div>
<div class="content">

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>

</div>

</div>
```